# Opening Facebook dialogue box in the same page

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

I have been trying to implement the [Facebook Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) as follows

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=12345678&redirect_uri=http://example.com&link=http://example.com&message=Hi+wassup!">
```

But the problem is it is opening the link in a page, rather than a pop up box.
Pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this as a dialog, you would need to use the [Facebook Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and call the  [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) function using the 'feed' value for method.

Comment: Im sure thats the right link, but Im not getting it right. Can you tell me how to open a dialogue like the eg. given in FB.ui when I click on a link?